# how to play multiple m3u8 in single Plyr with hlsjs

Tags: javascript, angular, hls.js

in my angular project, using of Plyr and ngx-plyr with hlsjs for playing stream m3u8.
no problem with one m3u8 but if exists two m3u8 in sources, playing  only one source.
how to play multiple m3u8 in single Plyr serially ?